# Android: is it possible to fire/emulate D-Pad KeyEvent?

Tags: android, keyevent

I have a game for Android that uses hardware keys (D-pad). There are lots of lines of code in my onKeyDown and onKeyUp callbacks throughout the program.

Now I'm trying to add support for a bluetooth gamepad, which generates its own events when various keys/sticks/triggers are pressed. And I would like to "mirror" these events from the gamepad as events from the D-pad, to use the existing onKeyDown and onKeyUp callbacks.

In other words I want to generate/emulate pressing of D-pad keys programmatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.UYhmwrWSr0s).

Use these:

```
int KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN   Key code constant: Directional Pad Down key.
int KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT   Key code constant: Directional Pad Left key.
int KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT  Key code constant: Directional Pad Right key.
int KEYCODE_DPAD_UP     Key code constant: Directional Pad Up key.
```

Check out the official [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: Seems like this can only be done either with the INJECT_EVENTS permission or on rooted device.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks. Is there any way to trigger D-pad long press events?